# Excitation spectrum of heisenberg model

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, symmetry-breaking

I understand that ferromagnetic Heisenberg model (lattice of spin variables that can point in any direction) spectrum can be deduced by a $\lambda\phi^4$ theory with $\phi$ being complex.

This model shows both massles (Goldstone) excitations and massive ones that we can understand with a mexican hat picture.

My question is: while we can interpret the Goldstone excitation as low energy magnons, what we can do with massive ones (i.e. transverse in the mexican hat picture). Which microscopic spin excitations do they represent?